# Issue base64 decoding a specific string

Tags: swift, base64, swift2

I have the following base64 encoded string and I need to base64 decode it using Swift:

> KimHser2RvFf9RPjajWO4K/odT51hTlISwMKNIfPUC+gXYZKNjGDCvHEom++6liXNq6PkStnpzMKBsTk+tIpJA==

There is no line break there, StackOverflow is just wrapping the string.  I have tried numerous methods to base64 decode this.  I do receive a result as NSData, however, when I try to convert the NSData to an NSString object, the result is always nil.  If I change the encoding to ASCII or UTF16 I receive a result, so I assume Swift is not recognizing the NSData in UTF8 format.  However, if I base 64 decode the same string in C#, UTF8 works, and the Base64 decoding works.  So I'm positive I'm missing a step due to my lack of experience with Swift.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
import Foundation

extension String {
// MARK: Base64 encode
func base64Encode() -> String {
    let data : NSData = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    return data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
}

// MARK: Base64 decode
func base64Decode() -> String {
    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: self, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    return decodedString as! String
}
}
```

I'm positive it's something easy.  However, this is my first application in Swift and I'm still learning.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `decodedData` is `<2a2987b1 ... fad22924>` which is definitely *not* a valid UTF-8 sequence. What result do you expect?

Comment: I'm trying to implement the Azure Shared Access Signature to query my Azure Storage Service from iOS.  This is the access key they give me (don't worry, I already reset my keys).  However, none of them work in Swift when trying to base64 decode into an NSString so I can use the decode string as the key to HMACSHA256 to generate the Shared Access Signature.

Comment: I don't know anything about Azure and the details of the Azure signature algorithm. But I strongly assume that you can use the *data* directly as the key to HMACSHA256, instead of converting it to a string first.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  All of the examples I have found so far use a String, but I'll investigate options just using NSData.

Answer (score 1):

Your "base64" string is invalid. If you try to decode it in [some online decoder](https://www.base64decode.org) it fails. But your code is valid :)
**Correction**
If original data that was encoded isn't a string data then I agree with @Martin R

Comment: The Base64 string *is valid*. It decodes to binary data which cannot be represented as NSString. The online decoder most probably fails because it also assumes that the decoded data represents a string in some encoding (UTF-8 or ISO Latin or ...)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not make that base64 string.  It's coming from another system.  Is there a way in Swift I can decode it to a NSString?  Eventually my goal is to take this base64 encoded string, decode it, then use the decode value as a HMACSHA256 key.  It's all part of authenticating with the Microsoft Azure Storage Service REST API.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case anyone other newbies need to hit the Azure Storage Service through REST and iOS Swift, below is the code that worked for me.  I used String extensions here only until I could figure it out.  This will end up in its own class.

```
    import Foundation

enum HMACAlgorithm {
    case MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512

    func toCCHmacAlgorithm() -> CCHmacAlgorithm {
        var result: Int = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
        case .SHA1:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
        case .SHA224:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
        case .SHA256:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
        case .SHA384:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
        case .SHA512:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
        }
        return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
    }

    func digestLength() -> Int {
        var result: CInt = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA1:
            result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA224:
            result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA256:
            result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA384:
            result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA512:
            result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
        }
        return Int(result)
    }
}

extension String {

    func hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm, key: String) -> String {
        let cKey = key.base64DecodeAsData();
        let cData = self.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var result = [CUnsignedChar](count: Int(algorithm.digestLength()), repeatedValue: 0)
        let strLen = Int(strlen(cData!))
        CCHmac(algorithm.toCCHmacAlgorithm(), cKey.bytes, cKey.length, cData!, strLen, &result)
        let hmacData:NSData = NSData(bytes: result, length: (Int(algorithm.digestLength())))
        let hmacBase64 = hmacData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding76CharacterLineLength)
        return String(hmacBase64)
    }

    func base64DecodeAsData() -> NSData {
        let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: self, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        return decodedData!
    }
}
```